# framed.sty deletes a following \label command when filling the last page of a document

Tags: framed

Under certain circumstances, when using framed.sty, a \label command
that occurs after a framed environment is lost, and nothing gets
written to the .aux file.  For this to happen, the framed material
must appear on the last page of the document, and must completely fill
that last page.

Here's a working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{framed}
\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
  \item ref-foo: \ref{foo} \qquad  pageref-foo: \pageref{foo}
\end{itemize}

\begin{framed}
  First line of the framed text
 
  \vspace{6.78in} % length chosen to push final line to bottom of page
 
  Final line of the framed text

\end{framed}

\label{foo} 

\end{document}
```

If you change the \vspace command to make the frame a bit larger, so
that the last line of the framed environment appears on the next page,
the .aux file will contain \newlabel{foo}{{}{1}}.  Similarly, if you
change the \vspace command to make the frame a bit smaller, that
\newlabel command will be in the .aux file.

Can anyone suggest a workaround?

Edit: I should mention that if you put a \leavevmode before the \label command, that adds an extra (blank) page to the document.

Comment: You can add `\leavevmode` just before `\label`.

Comment: @Bernard: Thanks, but (I should have mentioned) that causes an extra blank page to be added.  I'll edit the question to mention this.

Comment: It is supposed to label what?

Comment: @Bernard: It will be used in a \pageref command to reference the page on which a portion of the document ends, for a type of document that may or may not have a another portion of the document following this one.

Comment: Why not put it inside thr  framed environment?

Comment: @Bernard: Because the framed environment sometimes does not appear.  The long story: My exam documentclass uses framed.sty to format solutions to questions.  Those solutions are sometimes printed, and sometimes not.  A user wrote to me saying that he likes to be able to reference the page of end of the questions, which may or may not be followed by additional matter.  He also rearranges questions while editing, and so doesn't want to have to keep track of which question will be the last one.

Comment: @Bernard: I did find that `\vskip -4pt\hrule height 0pt depth 0pt` before the \label command works, but I'm hoping for something less of a kludge.

Comment: Your problem does not seem simple…

Comment: @Bernard: Yes, that's why I came here!